# How to deal with 2 useEffect hooks which may happen simultaniously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have an app where when the user sees the end of the page something is requested.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!isFetching && inView && cards.length !== props.totalCards) {
            requestCards(requestOptions, page, false)
        }
    }, [inView])
```

When I change the request options another hooks fires up

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isFetching) {
            requestCards(requestOptions, page, true)
        }
    }, [requestOptions])
```

Sometimes when the request ended and isFetching changed on false but the cards didn't appear, inView hook fires up and makes 1 more request.
How should I abort this bug?
I've tried to change dependency in hook on cards but then it doesn't request when user sees the bottom.

Comment: Are the request options really gonna change throughout the life of that component?

Comment: of course, it's the main feature

Comment: I guess I should put a kind of a check but I don't know what should I check

Comment: can you show me the whole code in codesandbox ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Alopwer/hearthstone-app

Comment: check if this is the behavior you want and if so I will tell what I did. https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-smoke-0ekob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209188/discussion-between-alopwer-and-mosmk).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, [you should avoid omitting props from your effect hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies). If you consolidate both of your `useEffects`, that may solve your issue. For example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(!isFetching) {
    if(inView && cards.length !== props.totalCards) {
      requestCards(requestOptions, page, false);
    } else {
      requestCards(requestOptions, page, false);
    }
  }
}, [isFetching, inView, cards, props.totalCards, requestOptions, page]);
```

Comment: it didn't solved the issue because these dependencies change to many times which triggers rerendering

Comment: What is causing the re-renders? Assuming the whole block is wrapped by the `!isFetching` condition, you should only ever be making API requests when you're not already. This effect may be run somewhat often; however, that shouldn't cause re-renders by itself. Changing state will cause re-renders.